# Is it possible to create image from Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am working on an app where users can log into the app and can enter text in a text form field. It can also apply different font styles and font families and generate an image from it.

Is it possible to achieve?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean an AI generated image?

Comment: can you elaborate more? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How about using screenshot? You can use `captureFromWidget` for invisible widget. https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example for you. You can test it in an app.
It draw the text to a canvas then save canvas as an image.  So you can apply any font style to ParagraphBuilder.

I hope it helps

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  Image? img;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: controller,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: _onPressedButton, child: const Text("Create Image")),
            Container(width: 200, height: 200, color: Colors.blueGrey, child: img ?? Container())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void getCanvasImage(String str) async {
    var builder = ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal));
    builder.addText(str);
    Paragraph paragraph = builder.build();
    paragraph.layout(const ParagraphConstraints(width: 100));

    final recorder = PictureRecorder();
    var newCanvas = Canvas(recorder);

    newCanvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, Offset.zero);

    final picture = recorder.endRecording();
    var res = await picture.toImage(100, 100);
    ByteData? data = await res.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

    if (data != null) {
      img = Image.memory(Uint8List.view(data.buffer));
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  void _onPressedButton() {
    getCanvasImage(controller.text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you can  use buider.pushStyle() for any style you want

Comment: The text and background was white. I add color to background
`newCanvas.drawColor(primaryColor,BlendMode.darken );`

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your text through External API like this https://rapidapi.com/seikan/api/img4me-text-to-image-service/ after that you need to download the image and show it to the user

Answer (score 1):

try [flutter_pixel](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pixel) package, an alternative to brain_fusion.
it provides a quicker way to generate images using AI.
hope this will help:

```html
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pixel/utilities/index.dart';

class ImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const ImageScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImageScreen> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<ImageScreen> {
  bool isTextEmpty = true;
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  Future<Uint8List> _generate(String query) async {
    textController.clear();
    setState(() {
      isTextEmpty = true;
    });
    Uint8List image = await imageGenerator(query, ImageSize.medium);
    return image;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    textController.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    Authenticator.setApiToken('your api-key'); // Replace this with your edenai API key (currently has a free plan as of 02/03/2024).

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: textController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Text to Generate Image',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: width,
                    child: !isTextEmpty
                        ? FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
                            future: _generate(textController.text),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return const Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
                              } else {
                                return Container();
                              }
                            },
                          )
                        : const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Enter Text and Click the button to generate the image',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 16,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (textController.text.isNotEmpty) {
            setState(() {
              isTextEmpty = false;
            });
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.art_track),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```